# OwlCarousel2 cannot get jquery to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm doing an slider image by using the plugin [OwlCarousel2](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)
I have added the JavaScript and CSS files that they provide on the website.

I'm also setup this on WordPress custom theme.  I having a hard time trying to figure out how to setup my own custom Jquery.

Custom animation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
        Boolean: false,
        Number: 10
    });
});
```

Wordpress Slider Image with Advanced Custom Gallery/Checkbox Fields

```
<?php $images = get_field('image_carousel');  ?>
    <?php $activate_carousel_array = get_field( 'activate_carousel' );  ?>

<?php if( $images ): ?>
<?php  if ( $activate_carousel_array ):
foreach ( $activate_carousel_array as $activate_carousel_item ):
echo $activate_carousel_item; ?>
<?php
$images = get_field('image_carousel');
if( $images ): ?>
<div id="hero">
<div class="slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
<div><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></div>
<?php endforeach; ?></div>
                   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php  endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use

`jQuery(document).ready(function()` and

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

remove one of them.

Comment: So I have remove the second $(document).ready(function() but still didn't work for me.